# Despite setting rootlogger to INFO/DEBUG, only error statements are printed. why?

Tags: java, logging

If I put info, only error log is printed.
If I put debug, only error log is printed.
Why is the logging level not working?

```
public class Test {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        log.info("info test");
        log.debug("debug test");
        log.error("error test");

    }

}
```

Console:

```
0 [main] ERROR com.testfiles.Test  - error test
```

log4j properties file:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, theConsoleAppender

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to call the BasicConfigurator directly if you have a properties file. Remove that call and the properties file should be picked up, provided it's on the classpath.

Comment: By removing that, I am getting the error "no appenders could found for the logger". It seems that log4j is not loading the property file from the location, I have given explicity using the VM argument(-Dlog4j.configuration="D:/Mani/Sync/log4j.properties"). Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Instead of BasicConfigurator, I used Property Configurator to load the properties file. It is working as expected. Thanks `PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");`